# NSXMLParser wont read XML feed

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

Im trying to parse this XML file: http://www.ep.samico.dk/data2.xml
But the NSXMLParser returns an error (domain error 5)
I think its because of the structure of the file, because when im trying to parse a file like this: http://www.ep.samico.dk/data.xml it works with no problem.. Can anyone tell me how to do it different?

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                    namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                   qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
                                      attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

NSLog(@"Started parsing %@", elementName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your reference link contains CDDATA tags..

I believe you need to handle CDDATA separately. you should implement this delegate as well and handle the data there.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
```

Comment: i think you saw the wrong file. Im not sure if im wrong but this file:http://www.ep.samico.dk/data2.xml does not contain any CDATA.. am i wrong? It is this file i having problems parsing: http://www.ep.samico.dk/data2.xml

Answer (score 0):

The error code 5 in `NSXMLParserErrorDomain` error domain is `NSXMLParserPrematureDocumentEndError`. That error means that the XML data is incomplete and it generally occurs because the parsed data is empty or `nil`.

I think you should check how the data is loaded. There's likely to be an error in the URL connection.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ep.samico.dk/data2.xml"]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if ( error )
        NSLog(@"URL error: %@", error);
    else
    {
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
        parser.delegate = self;
        if ( ! [parser parse] )
            NSLog(@"Parser error: %@", parser.parserError);
    }
}];
```

Comment: It returns no error, if i remove the if statement it returns URL error: (null)

Comment: And did the parser succeed to parse the XML data or did you still get an parsing error?

Comment: I'm not sure you get the expected data. What do you get with `NSLog(@"Data (%d): %@", [data length], [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);`?